# show div- element if $watch detected changes

Tags: angularjs, show-hide

I have a div- element

```
<div class="alert alert-success">
<a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
 CHANGE CHANGE CHANGE CHANGE ....
</div>
```

and my function is

```
$scope.$watch('customers.length', function() {

    // code ????????
}
```

Once $watch has detected a change of customers.length, the div should be displayed.
With `alert('....');` it works, but I will do it with a div element.

.

**Which code I have to write within my `function () { // code }` to realize it**

Answer (score 0):

Add the [ngShow](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angShow) or [ngIf](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angIf) directive to you div with an expression that becomes true when you watch function fires.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @Maurice's answer, you don't need to use a `$watch` expression.  Just use the `ng-show` attribute, as follows:

```
<div class="alert alert-success" ng-show="customers.length"> ... </div>
```

That will only show the `div` when the value for `$scope.customers.length` is truthy.

If you really *only* want to show the div when the value for `customers.length` changes (regardless of what the `.length` is), then you can do the following:

**In controller:**

```
...
$scope.origCustomersLength = $scope.customers.length;
...
```

**In your html:**

```
<div class="alert alert-success" ng-show="customers.length != origCustomersLength"> ... </div>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: It doesnt' work.

When I put in controller your suggested code, then nothing works. Not even the other codes on the site. :(

ng-show="customers.length != origCustomersLength" is OK but the other code in the controller must be changed.

Comment: no, of course. 
just put 
$scope.origCustomersLength = ;

I think the problem is "$scope.customers.length"

My customers via json-file.

        $http.get('customers.json').success(function(data) {
  $scope.customers = data;
  });  

I don't know, why i can use customers.length in HTML but not within my controller ??

Comment: The reason is because angular adds a watcher for all `ng-*` attributes, so it'll evaluate the expression after your `$http` request returns.  All you have to do is move the `$scope.origCustomersLength = $scope.customers.length;` statement to inside the .`success` function and it'll work.  You only want to execute that *after* the ajax call returns

Comment: hi tennisgent. Please check my answer to my question.